# I apparently have two different versions of Python installed on Debian; how can I remove the older one?

Tags: debian, python

[Here is the original question I posted on *Stack Overflow*.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768281/python-doesnt-find-modules-from-dist-packages/31768300?noredirect=1)

I’m on Debian and have Python 2.7.10 installed from sources (`compile && make && make install`) and 2.7.3 from an unknown origin.

It seems `pip` available from command line is from one Python and `python` from another. How to uninstall older Python or at least make all links point to one Python installation? How could this happen at all? Why Python from sources replaced link to Python but not to `pip`?

Comment: Can't you remove it with your package manager? Or remove all the Pythons and install the version you want then, so it won't get confused?

Comment: @Adalee can you explain in detail?

Comment: I don't use Debian, so I don't exactly know how you search for packages and how they are called, but can you look what output gives you `dpkg --get-selections | grep python` ? And then maybe uninstall the packages you don't want?

Answer (score 0):

[Debuild](http://blog.packagecloud.io/debian/debuild/packaging/2015/06/08/buildling-deb-packages-with-debuild/) is what you should be using to install foreign software.  The issue is that if you don't build and use a .deb package then apt-get, aptitude, synaptic, and the like aren't aware of the files you put into your file-system.  This will cause issues, as you are now aware, with upgrade and removing those unknown files.

Comment: One possible solution, if you still have or can re-create the make files, is to run 'sudo make uninstall' to have the make script remove the foreign files it put into your file-system.  Not all make scripts support the uninstall parameter however so it may or may not work.

Comment: How to install python from sources with debuild, or how to install latest python 2.7 with packet manager?

Comment: Debian is stable.  So stable that package upgrades tend to lag behind as the newer versions haven't been through enough testing as the older ones have.  If the newest version isn't in the apt-get repositories and you must build it from source then see the link I already gave: Debuild.

Answer (score 0):

when you run `which python` and `which pip` what do you get? chances are they will be symlinks to other executables in `/usr/bin/`. If you update your symlinks or run python directly (ex `/usr/bin/python2.7`), you can have both version installed side by side. I would definitely recommend using python virtual environments in the future and avoid mucking with your system python. They will allow you to run an entire python installation completely independent of your system's.

some good resources:

- https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org
  virtualenvwrapper is a nice tool for using virtualenvs. It allows you to list, manage, and switch between venvs with ease.
- http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/. this is a good doc on using virtualenvs